# Compare two nested lists and append a third list based on nested values - Python

Tags: python, list, compare, append, nested-lists

Nested list `A = [[1, 110, 150, 3], [5, 95, 155, 1], [4, 115, 195, 4], [2, 105, 205, 2]]`. I am trying to give a score to each of these individual lists which is calculated as `score = number of individual nested lists that have ( higher 3rd element value (3, 1, 4, 2) AND a presence in RanksList)`; where `Rankslist = []` initially.

So, basically an element needs to be added in each of the individual lists and `RanksList` becomes `RanksList = [[1, 110, 150, 3, x], [5, 95, 155, 1, x], [4, 115, 195, 4, x], [2, 105, 205, 2, x]]`; where `x` is the calculated score of each of the individual lists. This is what I have so far, and I am stuck:

```
      m = 0
      n = 0
      i = 0
      #RanksList = []
      A = [[1, 110, 150, 3], [5, 95, 155, 1], [4, 115, 195, 4], [2, 105, 205, 2]]
      duplicate_list = A[:]
      for m in A:
            for n in duplicate_list:
                  if (n[i][3] < m[i][3]) and (n in RanksList):
                         RanksList.append(m)
            i = i + 1
      print(len(RanksList))
      print(RanksList)
```

I have tried to duplicate the original `list A` and compare the third element in each of the nested list with the original nested list individually to fill in `RanksList`. I am a newbie to Python, and still shaky on lists. I am trying to do it without numpy. Thanks.

Comment: You'll never add anything to `RanksList` since it's initialized to `[]` at the beginning. But your `if` condition suppose your `RanksList` is not empty

Comment: `duplicate_list = A`
merely produces an alias: A new variable (i.e. just a new name in your program) referencing the same list, not a copy of it. If you alter it via one name, you'll see the altered list via the other name, too.

Comment: @SamBruns: I just assumed that I needed to initialize it to zero so that elements can be added later on. Even on removing it, I am unable to specifically check the 3rd element in every nested list with others (the ones I have called using `i`.

Comment: @das-g : Thanks for your response; being a newbie I wasn't aware of that. Is there another way I can compare the elements of the nested lists with its own? Thanks.

Comment: @das-g: Got it. I sliced it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your code carefully enough. As you don't alter either `A` nor `duplicate_list`, this probably doesn't matter. (But you could simply use `A` on both levels of iteration.

Comment: @das-g: I did the same, I tried the following:
    `for i in x: for j in y:  if i[3] < j[3]:  RanksList.append(j)`. But, I am unable to compare list1's elements with list2's elements individually; as the group comparison takes place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `for` doesn't need a variable for the indices. In the `for` the element of the current iteration will be available in the variable before the `in`. Thus, to access the inner lists's third element, you'll want something like

```
for m in A:
    for n in A:
        if (n[3] > m[3]): # no i
            # (increase score for m if n in RankList)
```

In the end `RankList` shall have an entry for each entry in `A`. But if we fill those into `RankList` from the beginning, your condition in the score calculation would be meaningless, so I guess that's not what you want. However, you'll have to fill in the values somewhen, and you cannot make that dependant on already present values, or it will never happen.

Maybe adding the value of the outer iteration once we've dealt with it is what you wanted:

```
RankList = []
for m in A:
    for n in A:
        if (n[3] > m[3]): # no i
            # (increase score for m if n in RankList)
    RankList.append(m)
```

Oops, syntax highlighting thinks `RankList` is a class, because it starts with a capital letter and continues mixed case. (The naming convention for python classes. Not enforced by the language, just a convention.) Let's rename it:

```
rank_list = []
for m in A:
    for n in A:
        if (n[3] > m[3]):
            # (increase score for m if n in rank_list)
    rank_list.append(m)
```

Now we can use it in the condition:

```
rank_list = []
for m in A:
    for n in A:
        if (n[3] > m[3]) and (n in rank_list):
            # (increase score for m)
    rank_list.append(m)
```

You wanted the lists in rank_list to have the score as the 5th element (i.e. at index `4`).

```
rank_list = []
for m in A:
    score = 0
    for n in A:
        if (n[3] > m[3]) and (n in rank_list):
            score += 1
    rank_list.append(m + [score])
```

But wait, `n in rank_list` will now always be false, because `rank_list` will contain **different** lists. Let's work with two separate lists, thus:

```
rank_list = []
already_scored = []
for m in A:
    score = 0
    for n in A:
        if (n[3] > m[3]) and (n in already_scored):
            score += 1
    rank_list.append(m + [score])
    already_scored.append(m)
```

Comment: I really love the step by step way you explained. It understood it well, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!